# How to make a query to get all groups of a user, showing the users that each group has (postgresql)

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, many-to-many

This is an issue that I thought easy at first, but haven't been able to solve it.

I got a table `users(id, username, email)` and another table `groups(id, name)`. I got a third table that stores the many-to-many relations between the other two, `groups_users(groupId, userId)`.

I want to make a query to get the groups which a certain user is member of. I also want that those queried groups contain the nested data of their respective users.
Translated to JSON, it would be something like:

```json
[
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'foo group',
    users: [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: 'bar',
        email: 'bar@foo.com'
      }
   ]
]
```

Any idea of the raw query I should make to Postgres for achieving this? I know that I would have to use funcionality of Postgres, that it also part of the question. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you use the same name for the primary key as you for their foreign keys then you use natural joints which doesn't require you to spell out the keys.  users(userId...), groups(groupId, ...).

Comment: Hm I'll consider doing that, thanks for the advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figure out what which groups the user is part of (g).  Then join that with groups_users to get those user_ids and join that with users to user_info.

```
select *
from (
  groups_users natural join 
  (select groupId from groups_users where userId = ?) g
)
join users on groups_users.userId = users.id
```

If you need the group name, join with that too.

Here is another way:

```
select *
from groups_users
join users on group_users.userId = users.id
where groups_users.gropId in (select groupId from groups_users where userId = ?)
```

Comment: But this won't give me the nested array of users inside each group as in the question, right? It would give me all the data at the same level. That is also part of my problem, I had also managed to get the user groups, but not both of the requirements at the same time (locating the groups **and** returning them with nested users)

Comment: SQL doesn't really have a concept of nested data.  You can use `select groupId, group_concat(....) ... group by 1`to smash user information into a row per group.  PostgresSQL has JSON support so you can probably convince it to give you the result as such.  It's not a bad idea, however, to build that json object on the client side in app code.

Comment: That's a good point. However, I'm using an ORM that automatically gives me nested relations from back, so I would like to keep it consistent. I can't use the mapper's functionality for this situation though, due to the nature of the query. I know SQL doesn't support nested data per se, but I would like to learn how to do it with PostgeSQL (I know it has some functions like you said, but I don't know how to use them)

Comment: Don't know anything about orms.  If this answered your postgresql question, mark it solved and ask a new orm question.

Comment: No it does not answer the question. A requirement of the question is using Postgres functionality to return the nested users, not only to find the groups.

Comment: I am confused... thought you said your orm did that?  Are you saying you want the result as json then?  Your question didn't say.  SQL doens't have a concept of "nested" tables.

Comment: Mm I do think I'm confusing concepts, you're right. I'll mark your answer as the correct one, thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

You could ask your database to create the json-output:

```
WITH cte(j) AS (
    SELECT
        jsonb_build_object(
                    'id'    , groupid
                ,   'name'  , name
                ,   'users' , json_agg(json_build_object(
                        'id'    , users.id
                    ,   'name'  , users.username
                    ,   'email' , users.email
                )
            )
        )
    FROM    groups_users
        JOIN    users ON users.id = userId
        JOIN    groups ON groups.id = groupId
    GROUP BY
        groupid, groups.id, groups.name
)
SELECT  json_agg(j)
FROM    cte;
```